# Add new place in Google Map using google api in swift

Tags: swift, google-places-api

I need to add a new location in google map. I understand that i need to create a request containing information about the new place in JSON format, what i needed is how to pass the request.
Thank in advance.

```
var dictionaryObject: NSDictionary = [
        "location": [
            "lat": "\(latitude)",
            "lng": "\(longitude)"
        ],
        "accuracy": 50,
        "name": "\(nameField.text)",
        "phone_number": "\(phoneNoField.text)",
        "address": "\(addressField.text)",
        "types": "\(typeField.text)",
        "website": "\(websiteField.text)",
        "language": "en-AU"
    ]

var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=API-KEY")!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var error: NSError?

    var theJSONData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
        dictionaryObject ,
        options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
        error: nil)
    var theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData!,
        encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    println((theJSONData))
    //request.HTTPBody = theJSONText?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPBody = theJSONData
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            var parseError: NSError?
            var responseObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? NSDictionary
             println((responseObject))

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the `addPlace` method from the Google Places API for iOS.  See the [Place Add guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/add-place) on the Google Developers site, which has code samples in both Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: I have already gone through the Google place guide. But i couldn't implement the swift code.

I have updated my Swift code..

Comment: What error do you get?  (i.e. what does `println(responseObject)` show?)  My point though is that using the Google Maps SDK for iOS means you don't need to muck about with JSON, instead you have a much easier API to work with.

Comment: println(responseObject) gives INVALID REQUEST

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the solution. It was a small mistake i send string for number for latitude and longitude. And the types should send array instead i send string.

Comment: Ah yep that would explain it :)  Using the SDK would help catch these errors at compile time, as you'd be using a `GMSUserAddedPlace` object with properties with useful types, as opposed to filling out a free-form JSON dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionaryObject: NSDictionary = [
    "location": [
        "lat": latitude,
        "lng": longitude
    ],
    "accuracy": 50,
    "name": "\(nameField.text)",
    "phone_number": "\(phoneNoField.text)",
    "address": "\(addressField.text)",
    "types": ["\(typeField.text)"],
    "website": "\(websiteField.text)",
    "language": "en-AU"
]

var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=API-KEY")!
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var error: NSError?

var theJSONData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
    dictionaryObject ,
    options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
    error: nil)
var theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData!,
    encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
println((theJSONData))
//request.HTTPBody = theJSONText?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = theJSONData
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        var parseError: NSError?
        var responseObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? NSDictionary
         println((responseObject))

}
```